OpenRiaServices request apparently blocking other requests
I have a strange problem with a client/server application using OpenRiaServices.
Everything works fine if I run the client and server on the same machine, and if I use something like Fiddler to monitor the network traffic when I run the client on my machine and connect to the remote server. The problem only happens when I run the client on my machine and connect directly to the remote server.
The situation is that I'm making two requests (A and B) to the server. Request "A" requires more processing on the server and can take several 10's of seconds but doesn't block the UI. Request "B" is much quicker, usually returning in a couple of seconds but does require the UI to be blocked.
What should happen (and does happen when I'm debugging) is this:

Make request "A".
Make request "B" which blocks the UI
Request "B" returns and user can carry on working
Request "A" returns.

What's actually happening is this:

Make request "A".
Make request "B" which blocks the UI
Request "A" returns.
Request "B" returns and user can carry on working

The code for request "A" is:
private void MakeRequestA()
{
    LoadOperation loadOpA = domainContextA.Load(domainContextA.RequestA(), LoadBehaviour.RefreshCurrent, true);
    loadOpA.Completed += LoadOpA_Completed;
}

private void LoadOpA_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Process results
}

The code for request "B" is basically the same:
private void MakeRequestB()
{
    // Block the UI

    LoadOperation loadOpB = domainContextB.Load(domainContextB.RequestB(), LoadBehaviour.RefreshCurrent, true);
    loadOpB.Completed += LoadOpB_Completed;
}

private void LoadOpB_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Process results

    // Unblock the UI
}

This is not a good user experience and we'd rather things happened in the order they're supposed to happen. How can I make the code behave itself?
